# cannot convert from 'FARPROC' to 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX)'

Tags: c++, winapi

```
BOOL (WINAPI *gmse)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX) = GetProcAddress(
                kernel32, "GlobalMemoryStatusEx");
```

This is in a .cpp file. While compiling the above code I am getting the below error.

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'FARPROC' to 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX)'
    This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I can't seem to figure out what should I cast the `GetProcAddress` function to.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast it to the function pointer type. To simplfy, use a `typedef` for the function pointer type:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *gmse_t)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX);

gmse_t gmse = (gmse_t)GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GlobalMemoryStatusEx");
```

The [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference page on MSDN provides example code.

Comment: it's a good idea to reserve ALL UPPERCASE identifiers for macros, to reduce the probability of unintentional text substitution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, point taken about the substitution. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the general pointer that you get from `GetProcAddress`.

So, instead of the current

```
BOOL (WINAPI *gmse)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX) = GetProcAddress(
            kernel32, "GlobalMemoryStatusEx");
```

do

```
auto const gmse = reinterpret_cast<BOOL (WINAPI*)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX)>(
   GetProcAddress( kernel32, "GlobalMemoryStatusEx" )
   );
```

In addition to adding that `const` I would use a more self-documenting name for that function pointer, like, well what about calling it `GLobalMemoryStatusEx`?

Answer (score 0):

Another, yet an elegant solution(which is just a polished version of Cheers' and hmjd's answers combined) can be this:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *gmse_t)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX);
gmse_t gmse;
gmse = reinterpret_cast<gmse_t>(
   GetProcAddress( kernel32, "GlobalMemoryStatusEx" )
   );
```